# Google Oauth2 redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: oauth-2.0

The weird thing is, that I have actually added the redirect url in the Cloud Console:

```
Request description:
    cookie_policy_enforce=false
    scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
    response_type=code
    access_type=online
    redirect_uri=http://dashboard.oversig.ht/auth/google/callback
    state=YnUoNnFFOWtyeyU6aClpYSJCcFNcQXpwR3BCVCc9OjEzODI3MDY4Mzc=
    display=page
    client_id=785509043543-5840itt4bu2dt8p11a177si3cvepuprb.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

In the cloud Console:

```
CLIENT ID
    785509043543-5840itt4bu2dt8p11a177si3cvepuprb.apps.googleusercontent.com
WEB ORIGIN
    http://dashboard.oversig.ht    −+
REDIRECT URI
    http://dashboard.oversig.ht/auth/google/callback    −+
```

Note: http://dashboard.oversig.ht/auth/google/callback doesn't need a trailing slash